# Laravel Sentinel Class Sentinel\Middleware\SentryAuth does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, sentinel

I have installed Sentinel package to my laravel web application.
Sentinel user login and activation is working good.
The issue is that i have added the miiddle ware to the route as follow

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['track', 'sentry.auth']], function () { 
    Route::Controller('state', 'StateController');
});
```

but i got that error

```
**Class Sentinel\Middleware\SentryAuth does not exist**
```

I checked the kernel.php and i found the middleware is already exists

```
 'sentry.auth' => \Sentinel\Middleware\SentryAuth::class,
 'sentry.admin' => \Sentinel\Middleware\SentryAdminAccess::class,
 'sentry.member' => \Sentinel\Middleware\SentryMember::class,
 'sentry.guest' => \Sentinel\Middleware\SentryGuest::class,
```